# Flip the image with canvas, DarkRoom

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I'm using the Dark Room script to manipulate images, I'm trying to add a custom plugin where the image should be reversed but I am not getting success.

The code of my plugin is this

```
function() {
    "use strict";
    var Flip = Darkroom.Transformation.extend({
        applyTransformation: function(canvas, img, next) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.scale(-1, 1) //not flip, whyy??
        }
    });
    Darkroom.plugins.flip = Darkroom.Plugin.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            var buttonGroup = this.darkroom.toolbar.createButtonGroup(),
                flipButton = buttonGroup.createButton({
                    image: "flip"
                });
            flipButton.addEventListener("click", this.flip.bind(this))
        },
        flip: function() {
            this.darkroom.applyTransformation(new Flip())
        }
    })
}()
```

Why do not flip? What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to work with canvas context, because have darkroom based on [FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/) and you can [setFlipX](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html#setFlipX) for image:

```
var Flip = Darkroom.Transformation.extend({
  applyTransformation: function(canvas, image, next) {
    image.setFlipX(!image.getFlipX());
    // do not forget to call next()
    next();
  }
});
```

`ctx.scale(-1, 1)` just changes [matrix of translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2D_computer_graphics#Translation) and doesn't change anything else.

Comment: You can help me more? My plugin to draw works but not save, see: http://pastebin.com/s65ZJkMh

Comment: if you want to draw on a canvas, it shoudn't be a `Transformation`, it should be `Plugin`. You can take a look on a [demo](http://mattketmo.github.io/darkroomjs/) and source code of [crop](https://github.com/MattKetmo/darkroomjs/blob/master/lib/js/plugins/darkroom.crop.js) plugin